# How to place latex-like mathematical formulas (e.g. via mathjax) in Haskell Diagrams?

Tags: haskell, mathjax, haskell-diagrams

I am attempting to place latex-style math formulas into a haskell diagram.

The documentation pages
http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#essential-concepts
and
http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/tutorials.html
suggest that one can use something called 'mathjax' to achieve this.

Is there an explanation or example somewhere of how to actually code this?

---

Attempting to follow the documentation at those links, my best guess for how would be something like:

```
mathDiagram :: Diagram B
mathDiagram = stroke $ textSVG "`2 + \sqrt{\pi}`:math:" 1
```

But this of course gives an error:

```
induction.hs:13:35: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 's'
```

Comment: Put `$` before and after the Latex code instead of `\``

Comment: The lexical error is easy to fix: escape your backslashes, as in ```"'2 + \\sqrt{\\pi}`:math:"```. No idea whether that's enough to reach your goal, though; probably not.

Comment: I don't think there's any supported way to get LaTeX formulæ in diagrams. What the [diagrams tutorial](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/tutorials.html) says about LaTeX is only meta, about _this particular documentation_, i.e. it says you can include LaTeX if you're editing `projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc`, which as a browser-displayed page supports MathJax easily. I reckon it would _in principle_ also be possible to import math stuff as some MathJax-rendered SVG back into generic diagrams, but this is certainly not as simple as writing something like `textSVG "$2 + \\sqrt{\\pi}$"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `diagrams-pgf` backend. Just use the `text` function and put dollar signs around your text.  Also, see here for an explanation of how to include diagrams in a LaTeX document: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/latex.html .

Comment: Is that `text` function defined within `diagrams-pgf`? I don't see one there.

Comment: No, `text` is from `diagrams-lib`.

Comment: I see it [there](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.0.1/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Text.html). Thank you!